# Connection between MSSQL and PHP 5.3.27 on Apache 2.2 is not working

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, apache

On a Windows 2003 (32-bit) environment running:

- Apache HTTPD 2.2
- PHP 5.3.27 Thread-safe

I've installed the Microsoft SQL Server Native Client for 32-bit, and from the driver download I've copied php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll to C:\PHP\ext (and confirmed this is set as extension_dir).

I've also tried the PDO version of the driver and the VC6 versions (have confirmed it's VC9 though).

Restarting HTTPD does not report any errors and does serve pages okay; accessing a page containing phpinfo() includes the config section of:

```
cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--disable-isapi" "--enable-debug-pack" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze"
```

Searching the page for SQLSERV or MSSQL returns no results confirming it's not started with the MSSQL extension loaded.

As a test I've had PHP connect to SQL server using:

```
new COM('ADODB.Connection')
```

This can access the SQL Server instance okay.

Any thoughts on what else to try, or any extra info required?

Comment: [loading the php driver at startup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296203(v=sql.105).aspx) => Do you have `extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll` somewhere in you php config (as just having it in the dir doesn't enable it yet)?

Comment: yup, the php.ini in use was modified everytime I tried a different extension (and Apache HTTPD restarted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out even thought HTTPD said it had restarted (repeatedly) it wasn't restarting... the joys of Apache HTTPD on Windows :s